# JSON.NET Serialization Tracing - Error loading type from assembly - ITraceWriter

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, trace

I'm debugging a C# class library that uses JSON.NET for serialization.  There is a conversion error during deserialization, so I implemented serialization tracing using the example code http://james.newtonking.com, Release 11 notes (dated 11/2012).  My code:

```
ProcessPlan p = ProcessPlan.TestPlan();
ITraceWriter traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, new JsonSerializerSettings { TraceWriter = traceWriter });

Console.WriteLine(traceWriter);
```

When this code runs, I receive this message:

CPlanAppV9.UnitTest.TestRepository.SaveLoad:
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type   'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ITraceWriter' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

The DLL referenced in project References claims its version to be 5.0.3, which is what I want.  I cannot get the Version attribute in the above error message to show anything but 4.5.0.0, although it may be referring to the Framework version number.

I removed all references to the library, cleaned the Solution, rebuilt, and then re-installed the 5.0.3 package through NuGet, but the 'type loading' problem persists, as does the 4.5.0.0 in the error message and Reference entry Properties.  I do have other projects, now completed, that were built with earlier versions, so this could be a flavor of DLL Hell.

Comment: from JSON.NET release notes: "Note that the assembly version number of Json.NET 5.0 hasn't changed and is still 4.5.0.0 to avoid assembly redirect issues."

You might want to check the file version instead of the assembly version to find out the right version

Comment: Thanks, corrego.  The File Version is what I need it to be, so the failure to load the ITraceWriter type is still a mystery.

Comment: Did you check that the json.net assembly in the bin folder is the right one?

Comment: Yes, I did.  It is the correct one, according to the File Version.

Comment: hmmm you could try activating the fusion log and checking there if the correct file is being loaded... other than that, i'm running out of ideas :) good luck

Comment: Same issue here.  Is there any resolution?